# Why do we have an appendix according to Torah sources?

Tags: medicine, science, parts-of-the-body

Is there any significance in Torah literature, attributed to the appendix and its function in the body?

Comment: In case this question is premised on the uselessness of the appendix, it bears mentioning that the premise is not true. The appendix supplements the body's immune functions; it contains lymphoid tissue and retains beneficial gut bacteria.

Comment: @Fred Although I did actually have that premise, which you have now corrected, I didn't have it in mind with regards to the question. I know there is literature on the significance of various parts of the body in general, so I was asking what do we say about the appendix (regardless of whether it is considered useful or useless)

Comment: Does anybody know if the appendix is ever mentioned in classic (early - pre 20th century) Torah sources?